# how to get client ip with blazor .net 6 (webassembly)

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, .net-6.0, blazor-webassembly

I'm trying to get the ip of the user who is accessing the page, but I can't make a request to get the ip, because I don't know how to solve this 'cors' problem.

`Access to fetch at 'https://api.ipify.org/?format=json&callback=JSONP_CALLBACK' from origin 'http://localhost:5200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`

[image]

I tried to add addCors, but it doesn't exist in a webassembly application

Comment: Let's start with why a client side app would need the client ip?

Comment: @Senhor Magoo save to a database

Answer (score 2):

No matter how to do it, when you want to get the client ip, a client side app(Blazor Webassembly) will return the ip as ***127.0.0.1***. I used the following codes to test it:

```
<script src="https://pv.sohu.com/cityjson?ie=utf-8"></script>
<script>
    window.getip = () => {
        console.log(returnCitySN["cip"]);
    };
</script>
```

You can see the result of test, which returned the 127.0.0.1:
[image]

Back to your issue here, you can do little in blazor webassembly app to solve the CORS issue. From your screenshot, I can see you want to call the api. You can try to set the CORS rules in the api website.

Also, you can try to use the server-side app like blazor server, which can achieve your goal. What's more, if you choose not to use the server-side app, I found this line of code which can also do that:

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="https://www.hashemian.com/js/visitorIP.js.php"></script>
```

Here is the test result of it:
[image]